# PL/SQL What am I doing wrong?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
updated_commission float;
cur_var a%rowtype;
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('EMPLOYEE_NO     FNAME     LNAME     COMMISSION');
dbms_output.put_line('-----------------------------------------------');
WHILE cur_var%found AND COMMISSION IS NOT NULL
LOOP
CASE BRANCH_NO
  WHEN 100 THEN updated_commission := COMMISSION * 1.10
  WHEN 101 THEN updated_commission := COMMISSION * 1.15
  WHEN 104 THEN updated_commission := COMMISSION * 1.20
  dbms_output.put_line(cur_var.EMPLOYEE_NO||'       '||cur_var.FNAME||'       '||cur_var.LNAME||'     
'||cur_var.COMMISSION||'      '||cur_var.updated_commission);
END LOOP;
END;
```

(Keeps giving me an error about my CASE statement and I cannot find out what is wrong, please help) PS (Has to be a while loop for the assignment)

Comment: Does your `CASE` statement end?

Comment: how do i end the case statment?

Comment: . . https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems004.htm.

Comment: Besides the issue of the case statement, your script has big issues (case problem is small). I suggest you do a little study on cursor. A cursor references the result of a select statement, yet you have no select. Even if it were properly defined your use is incorrect. You failed to to open it, which actually runs select, and failed to fetch from it (which makes a row of data available), the would cause the the test cur_var%found to be NULL so the where never executes. Read/Study Oracle Cursor then come back with any questions on parts you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I *fixed* only the `CASE`, didn't look at other stuff as we don't know anything about `CUR_VAR` - how it gets its value, what `COMMISION` is etc..

```
DECLARE
  updated_commission float;
  cur_var a%rowtype;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('EMPLOYEE_NO     FNAME     LNAME     COMMISSION');
  dbms_output.put_line('-----------------------------------------------');
  WHILE cur_var%found AND COMMISSION IS NOT NULL
  LOOP
    updated_commision := commision * 
      case when branch_no = 100 then 1.10
           when branch_no = 101 then 1.15
           when branch_no = 104 then 1.20
      end;
  dbms_output.put_line(cur_var.EMPLOYEE_NO||'       '||cur_var.FNAME||'       '||cur_var.LNAME||'     
    '||cur_var.COMMISSION||'      '||cur_var.updated_commission);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As another way to fix your CASE statement you might consider:

```
DECLARE
  updated_commission  NUMBER;
  cur_var             a%rowtype;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('EMPLOYEE_NO     FNAME     LNAME     COMMISSION');
  dbms_output.put_line('-----------------------------------------------');

  WHILE cur_var%found AND COMMISSION IS NOT NULL
  LOOP
    CASE BRANCH_NO
      WHEN 100 THEN updated_commission := COMMISSION * 1.10
      WHEN 101 THEN updated_commission := COMMISSION * 1.15
      WHEN 104 THEN updated_commission := COMMISSION * 1.20
    END CASE;

    dbms_output.put_line(cur_var.EMPLOYEE_NO || '       ' ||
                         cur_var.FNAME       || '       ' ||
                         cur_var.LNAME       || '         ' ||
                         cur_var.COMMISSION  || '      ' ||
                         updated_commission);
  END LOOP;
END;
```